# find all labels and empty the text

Tags: jquery

I am unable to find a way of being able to set the text() of a label to empty using this method:

```
 lastTableRow.find("label").each(function(){
 });
```

how can I iterate through a table row element (lastTableRow) and find **all label elements within that row** and empty the text?

UPDATE:

doing: lastTableRow.find("label").text() works as explained by @u_mulder

the problem I now face, which I didn't expect, is that it would remove the text from all labels in the table.

So I am cloning a previous row:

```
var lastTableRow = $('#mainTable tr:last').clone();
```

Then doing:

```
    lastTableRow.find("label").text('');
```

at which point the row I had just cloned loses the values of its labels when I want it to stay intact.

The function is being called, to do all of this, on a button click.

**EDIT**

Second part of the question/problem I am having:

This is what I am doing:

```
function CloneRow()
{
    var oldLastTableRow = $('#mainTable tr:last');
        oldLastTableRow.find(".CmdGetName").remove();
        oldLastTableRow.find(".LblCasName").remove();

        var lastTableRow = $('#mainTable tr:last').clone();
        lastTableRow.attr('id', 'row_' + rowIDNumericOnly); // rename the id

        // clear out existing label texts
        lastTableRow.find("label").text('');

    $('#mainTable tr:last').after(lastTableRow);
}
```

Comment: `lastTableRow.find("label").text()`?

Comment: Could you post a complete code example please?

Comment: The posted code changes the elements ID, and has nothing to do with neither text nor values ?

Comment: @u_mulder quick edit to set an empty value:`.text('')`

Comment: Not sure why people aren't seeing the question CLEARLY. I have it working for input types but now I want to FIND ALL LABELS IN A TABLE ROW and set the text value to empty. I cannot just do .text('') because I would need to specify the elementID, at which point I do not have this.

Comment: Because you don't understand what jQUery selector returns. It returns collection of objects and if you don't need something special on them there's no need to use `each`. it's just overhead. @Dheed thanks. but I can't edit my comment after 10 minutes(

Comment: thanks @u_mulder - your response initially worked. The problem I face now is that it would remove the text of the labels from the entire DOM when I only want it for a table row. lastTableRow is retrieving by doing a clone on the last tr of a table

Comment: @Ahmedilyas how do you choose which row you need to clean? or which row you need to clean

Comment: @Dheed - I do a clone on a button click and then do these advanced functions. So the cloned item is the one I need to clear out as the previous row will contain data in labels and I want the new row to be clean.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas so you basically want a new row with the same information as the clicked one( except the label) plus the old one?

Comment: @Dheed = almost. basically the same row but have the inputs emptied and renamed (which I have all done) and adding some new elements (which I have also done). Just want the row to clear all labels. I managed to have this done but noticed that it also seems to clear the labels of the the previous row I have cloned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/bufeqa/1/edit)***

You can use `.text("")`, `.html("")`, or `.empty()` Methods.

```
lastTableRow.find("label").text("");
```

<sub>(if `lastTableRow` is really a jQuery collection of HTMLelements :) )</sub>

so yes, as you can see you don't need to `.each()` loop (unless you need to perform advanced tasks). `.find()` already returns a collection of elements forwarded to the chained `.text("")` for clearance. All will be cleared.

***Edit:*** to reflect your edit, to `.clone()` and `.empty()` and `.append()` an element, refer to the following example: [demo](http://jsbin.com/bufeqa/4/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Thanks. So the problem I discovered was that it would clear out all the labels on the previous row which I cloned. I don't quite want that but only for the new row I have cloned but keep the previous row still in tact

Comment: @Ahmedilyas in this example http://jsbin.com/bufeqa/2/edit you can see that what you're saying is not true. The previous LABEL elements are not cleared since they're not in the `:last` TR element. I probably need from you a HTML sample to further help you (currently it's not clear enough).

Comment: @Ahmedilyas here I created a simplified version to give you some ideas: http://jsbin.com/bufeqa/4/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: thanks. That makes sense. I seem to have another problem unfortunately where for whatever reason, when I clone the row, it seems to append another label I create dynamically on the fly for that row.

Comment: my own fault... anyway, all fixed it appears. thanks very much